# dig "hostname_1" @"IP" command

Tags: dns, dig

I was told to execute the command: `dig "hostname_1" @"IP"`.

I don't know  what it is for, any idea? and the meaning of "@IP"?

Another question, the response has the field:

```
;;AUTHORITY SECTION:

"hostname_1" 1200 IN NS "hostname_2"

"hostname_1" 1200 IN NS "hostname_3"
```

Is it correct that hostname_2 and hostname_3 are another names for hostname_1?or are they nameservers of the hostname_1 host?

Comment: The general solution to these types of questions is using `man`. In this case, execute `man dig`, and the documentation for the command will be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dig is a tool for performing DNS lookups.

Normally dig asks your locally configured nameserver, however, with @IP you can make dig ask the nameserver which runs on the specified IP.

The output of dig can be read a follows KEY, TTL (time to live in seconds), CLASS (normally "IN" for Internet), TYPE, RDATA (resource data) (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_record for a longer description)

There are a number of types (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types), NS means "nameserver". In your case hostname_2 and hostname_3 are the responsible nameservers for hostname_1.

Comment: Excelent thks!!The only thing i don't understand is what you mean by "hostname_2 and hostname_3 are the responsible nameservers for hostname_1",excuse my ignorance and thank you so much for your answer.